# How to use Angular behind Basic Auth protection?

Tags: angular, basic-authentication, angular8, http-status-code-401

We have an Angular 8 Application that runs on an Apache and on nginx. We protect this application using Basic Auth with `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd`.

Unfortunately the app won't load due to requests to the server that are blocked by the Basic Auth and Angular can't load these files:

> Blocked http://root/polyfills-es2015.js from asking for credentials because it is a cross-origin request.
>   Blocked http://root/runtime-es2015.js from asking for credentials because it is a cross-origin request.
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Authorization Required) (runtime-es2015.js, line 0)
>   Blocked http://root/styles-es2015.js from asking for credentials because it is a cross-origin request.
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Authorization Required) (styles-es2015.js, line 0)
>   Blocked http://root/vendor-es2015.js from asking for credentials because it is a cross-origin request.
>   Blocked http://root/main-es2015.js from asking for credentials because it is a cross-origin request.
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Authorization Required) (vendor-es2015.js, line 0)
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Authorization Required) (main-es2015.js, line 0)
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Authorization Required) (polyfills-es2015.js, line 0)

If we remove the reference to the `.htpasswd` the application runs as expected.

I tried to use a custom HTTP Interceptor:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  const cloned = req.clone({
    headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('user:password'))
  });

  return next.handle(cloned);
}
```

But it seems, that this is not used for Angulars internal loading mechanism.

How can we get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not located in your Angular code but rather in the backend configuration.

You need to enable CORS (Cross-origin requests) in your backend. Right now, your backend does not allow the requests to go through to prevent any website to send a request (prevents from cross-site scripting attacks).

Thus, you should look in `nginx` and `Apache` how to enable CORS. This website seems to give a short & good introduction: https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html. Beware to restrict the allowed origins though, so you don't leave open doors to potential attackers.

Comment: Oh boy, so this is still a CORS issue. Thank you. We thought as it only happens with Basic Auth enabled, that it is related to that instead. Thank you.